# How to install latest Scipy version on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, pip

I currently have Raspbian OS

and I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib ipython ipython-notebook python-pandas python-sympy python-nose
```

which worked fine but installed an old version (0.10)

And:

```
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev gfortran python-pip

sudo pip install scipy
```

which after more than an hour working ended up with some errors.

What did you do to install Scipy 0.12 on your Raspberry?

Comment: Can you give the exact error message?

Comment: Also, here is a blog post about installing scipy on the  Raspberry Pi: http://wyolum.com/numpyscipymatplotlib-on-raspberry-pi/

Answer (score 18):

TL;DR: skip to the last paragraph to know how to increase swap space and avoid memory clogging. Also, don't use pip for numpy and scipy.

To get the latest version of scipy on the raspberry Pi you need to build from source. The main reason is that scipy relies on compiled C and fortran libraries, that need to be compiled on the same architecture. Usually `pip install` would fetch prebuilt packages for you, but Raspberry Pi's ARM architecture is not really supported.

If this was all you needed it would be relatively easy (main instructions can be found [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.0.0/INSTALL.rst.txt) and are summarized below), but there is an additional problem with the raspberry pi that I realized only after a week of research and trial and error (skip at the end if you just need the fix), which is due, I believe, to the small amount of memory available.

I'll just try and summarize the whole process (so that people don't have to jump around the internet like I did).

### Requirements

There are a few requirements for building scipy. As far as python packages go, you'll need `numpy`, `cython`, `setuptools`, and (if you want to build the documentation) `Sphinx`.
You should try and use the version of these packages that comes with Raspbian (in packages such as `python3-numpy`), but they might need to be built separately (OT).

As far as system requirements go, you'll need a few packages that can be installed with `apt-get`, namely:

- A BLAS/LAPACK math library with development headers, e.g. `libopenblas-base` and `libopenblas-dev`;
- `python-dev`;
- C and Fortran compilers, `gcc` and `gfortran`;

Finally you need the source code, that you can download from [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/archive/v1.0.0.tar.gz) (Scipy 1.0.0 is the latest stable version as I am writing).
Then it's just a matter of

`tar -xzvf scipy-v1.0.0.tar.gz
cd scipy`

### Compiling the source

At this point, if you start the build process, it will seem to go fine, but it will hang after a few minutes.

#### Adding bigger swap space

This is due to the compiling script occupying the totality of both RAM and swap memory by spawning multiple processes (and replicating memory by consequence). The problem is that in the Raspberry Pi the swap space is particularly small (only 100MB I think), while the norm would be to have it the same size of your RAM.

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19595944/trouble-installing-scipy-in-virtualenv-on-a-amazon-ec2-linux-micro-instance/20890162) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173972/how-do-you-add-swap-to-an-ec2-instance), swap space can be increased typing the following:

```
sudo /bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=1024
sudo /sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1
sudo chmod 600 /var/swap.1
sudo /sbin/swapon /var/swap.1
```

which will give you 1GB of swap space.

Then one can finally build and install with

```
python3 setup.py build

python3 setup.py install --user
```

(you can drop the `--user flag` if you want to install it system-wide, but you'll need root privilege).

Finally, one remove the extra swap and restore the default:

```
sudo swapoff /var/swap.1
sudo rm /var/swap.1
```

Comment: I have been solving few days this memory issue with raspberry. Men you saved my life.

Comment: @zurfyx IMHO this post should be marked as the answer

Comment: Thanks @jlandercy, I was hoping for that but I'm afraid the OP has abandoned the platform.

Comment: Absolute props - was able to successfully compile scipy-1.9.3-cp38-cp38-linux_armv7l.whl on my rpi4

Answer (score 8):

Install using a wheels for pi. It may not be the very latest scipy but it's quite up to date.

- update pip: `pip install pip --upgrade` (or `pip3`, adapt to your python version)
- go to https://www.piwheels.org/simple/scipy/
- select the scipy version and target platform (ex. armv6l for pi zero and earlier pi; armv7l for 3)

  - example: `scipy-1.2.1-cp35-cp35m-linux_armv7l.whl` on a 3 model B
- download the .whl file

  - using for example: `wget https://www.piwheels.org/simple/scipy/scipy-1.2.1-cp35-cp35m-linux_armv7l.whl#sha256=270be300233af556e6ee3f55a0ae237df0cb65ac85d47559010d7a9071f2e878`
- go to where the `.whl` file was downloaded and: `pip install the-scipy-file.whl`

**Notes**:

- this can be done in a virtualenvironment (just tested)
- this is *way* faster than any other method I've seen or tried.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you @calocedrus. I had to add a `--no-check-certificat` to the wget command, but that's just me.

Answer (score 3):

Debian, as goldilocks pointed out, doesn't always ship with the latest versions of packages. Sometimes it ships with *really ancient* versions, like its Netpbm distribution, which is over 12 years out of date.

There are two ways of dealing with this:

1. **Live with it**: are you sure you really have to have the latest version? If your code requires functions or bugfixes from the latest version, then this isn't an option. Debian packages are usually pretty stable, so if you can make your code work with it, you won't have to worry about maintaining your own upgrades. Here are the [SciPy 0.10.0 Release Notes](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/release.0.10.0.html) — would these features work?
2. **Build from source**: the easiest way to get the source dependencies for the *current* release is to use `apt-get build-dep` — but it needs a source line in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

   - To `/etc/apt/sources.list`, add the line: 
     `deb-src http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi`
     (basically, the same as the `deb` line, but with `deb-src`. If you don't, apt will complain.)
   - Now issue `sudo apt-get build-dep python-scipy` ; this returns a large list of packages, many more than your post included. Your error message may have been about missing dependencies.
   - Try building scipy again.

Note that there may still be dependency issues, as the current version (0.14 or so) may require newer dependent packages than Raspbian knows about. If you can, try to use a tool like `checkinstall` that will tell Raspbian that you've installed a newer version with special dependencies, so that it shouldn't get stomped all over in routine upgrades. This process is a bit fiddly; some pointers on how to do it are here: [How to build a Debian/Ubuntu package from source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130894/how-to-build-a-debian-ubuntu-package-from-source)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a python user, but the (probable) reason for the old version is that it's debian policy to take a sometimes excessive amount of time to update versions, plus the package may be obscure (hence updated even less), plus raspbian itself is pretty obscure in relation to debian (hence the packages there are updated even less).  Ie, it's a consequence of available resources (the people who maintain the packages, who are usually not the upstream developers).

> after more than an hour working ended up with some errors

Presumably this is an issue with compiling one or more of the modules, although you did not actually say what the error was.  Compiling python modules should *mostly* work on the pi, I think, but keep in mind it is an unusual architecture for such, with libraries compiled specifically for it.  Unfortunately, this brings the risk of previously unnoticed bugs in some part or another surfacing (if you want to find bugs in a compiled language -- parts of some python modules are in C -- try compiling the code on a few different platforms, lol...).  Locating the culprit would take a bit more work and attending to the specific errors.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to install scipy with "pip install scipy", after many attempts, by increasing swap size to 2048 on a Raspberry 4 with 2 Gb.

Answer (score 1):

1) Increase swap to 1GB

```
sudo dphys-swapfile swapoff
sudo vim /etc/dphys-swapfile
```

> CONF_SWAPSIZE=1024

```
sudo dphys-swapfile swapon
```

2) Reboot to apply swap changes

```
sudo reboot
```

3) Than build, here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3-alpine
MAINTAINER codertarasvaskiv

RUN apk add --no-cache g++ gfortran python3-dev openblas-dev bash
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir numpy
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir scipy
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir <my custom package>

ENTRYPOINT ["bash"]
```

So it takes 10 mins to  build numpy, than almoust 3 hours to build scipy in container.

Answer (score 1):

On some distributions (e.g. Arch Linux Arm), there are pre-compiled packages available such as `python-scipy`,  `python-numpy` and  `python-matplotlib`. Depending on the Python version that is default in the distro and your requirements, it may also be `python3-*`. You will possibly need to remove previously installed packages and their dependencies for these packages to be installed from the distro repos instead of from `pip`. The Python package [`pip-autoremove`](https://pypi.org/project/pip-autoremove/) can be helpful for that because `pip` does not remove any dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to install on `Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)` by using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib python3-numpy python3-scipy python3-opencv python3-pandas python3-dev
```

No need for pip or compiling from source.

Answer (score 0):

Tried a lot of above but one answer lead me to https://www.piwheels.org/project/scipy/ where I followed the two line instructions and finally installed scipy easily.
Maybe it took the whole combination of what I did earlier but scipy is installed now.

Comment: It is far easier to run `sudo apt install python3-scipy`