# Python 3.6 on Rpi3 Raspbian isn't default after install

Tags: python, pi-3

On a fresh install of Raspbian Jessie+PIXEL (1/11/17 release), I installed from the source *Python 3.6.0*.

I downloaded the `tgz` file from Python.org and built from source. I used a couple of sources to research install to ensure I didn't do anything abnormal or wrong in process and they match with what is answered in the [Raspberry Pi SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/59381/how-do-i-update-my-rpi3-to-python-3-6) regarding install of Python 3.6.0 (*the only thing I did different was using `sudo -s` as a separate command in the terminal before any other command*.)

When downloading, the `tgz` file defaults to the `/home/pi/Downloads` folder and extracting creates the folder `/Python-3.6.0` inside of that. After running the commands for install I can see the python executable which will open *LX-Terminal* and state use of *python 3.6*

When I browse other packaged versions of Python (2.7, 3, 3.4), each of the have an IDLE folder with the associated IDLE IDE executable but the Python 3.6 folder after install does not have an IDLE folder nor does Python 3.6 have a separate folder in `/usr/lib` as the other versions. Additionally, if I enter `python` on the command line, it starts Python *2.7*. If I run IDLE (3), it starts up IDLE for Python *3.4*.

**Update**:

I blew away the SD card and reapplied the Raspbian image and went through the steps again, making certain I created a directory in path.

I can set the terminal to run Python 3.6 if I start the terminal app from the desktop but it still defaults to 2.7 from command line, and IDLE still defaults to 3.4.2.

How do I get Raspbian to use Python 3.6 as the default version from the terminal and when starting IDLE 3?

Comment: It's likely not appearing because it's being installed in /usr/local/bin, and the system Python is in /usr/bin, ahead of it in your PATH statement. You risk making your system hard to administer by altering the system Python interpreter. Use something like [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv "pyenv") instead.

Comment: So would then I blow it away (nothing on it) and use pyenv? Or does pyenv let me keep what is there and just make global settings, further controlling it from there. I wasnt clear on that at the main PyEnv site

Comment: don't blow away the system Python interpreter, as it will take unspecified bits of your system with it. pyenv should be able to allow you to run 3.6 for your local stuff while keeping whatever the system has as its version of Python. This is a good thing. You also need to keep Python 2.7 around as 'python' for system stability

Comment: OK. I'll give that a shot. Thanks for the advice. I'll let you know if that worked.

Comment: Solved. When I stopped over-thinking pyenv, it was wonderful. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### System Default

As you may be aware, there are many directories in which Linux places binaries, or executable files.  These are the commands executed on the terminal.

One of the common directories is `/usr/bin`.  You can learn which binary will be run when you type in a command by using `which`:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

You'll find that many applications install binaries to this, or other directories.  You may also notice that Python installs here, but the binaries have the version as a suffix:

```
$ ls /usr/bin | grep python
python
python2.7
python3.7
```

Ah, then what is `python`?

```
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root toot 7 Oct 12 12:13 /usr/bin/python -> python3
```

It's a symbolic link, pointing to whichever version of Python is the default version for the system.  You *could* play with this manually, but on Debian systems we can take advantage of `update-alternatives`, and using the right tools will prevent future issues.

```
$ update-alternatives --config python
```

You will be asked to select from the available versions.  If you start to compile binaries of your own, or have another situation where you want to add your own alternatives, you can do that using `update-alternatives` as well.

### Python Default

Python scripts, and scripts of many other languages are designed with a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) at the top of the file, which is used to determine which program is used to load the script.  You're probably familiar with the `bash` shebang, `#!/bin/bash`.

For Python, the 'default' or common example is `#!/usr/bin/env python`.  You can adjust this to your needs:  `#!/usr/bin/env python3`.  This directly maps to the names of the files of the python binaries.  You can choose `python`, `python3`, or `python3.7` and get as specific or ambiguous as you wish, though you'll probably want to specify only the major version, so `python3` or `python2`.

This is used when the file is executable (`+x`) and you run the file as an executable:

```
$ ./path/to/script
```

Whereas you can ignore the shebang, or specify which program runs the script:

```
$ python ./path/to/script
$ python3 ./path/to/script
$ python3.7 ./path/to/script
```

This means that you can either take advantage of specifying the Python version at the top of each file, or when calling the file.

---

### Making a choice

Normally, `update-alternatives` is the ideal solution for having binaries of the same package name at different versions.  With Python, though, I'd recommend keeping the defaults which comes with the distribution, and using the correct Python version in the shebang/environment loaded with each Python script.  This will help prevent issues with system upgrades, `pip2` and `pip3`, etc, and will also help keep your upgrade path clear so that you can convert your Python 2 scripts into Python 3 over time.

If you're not familiar, take a look at [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) and how you can isolate Python and any dependencies you install even further and in a way that is easier to replicate on different systems.

Consider [Sublime Text 3](https://www.sublimetext.com/3) and [ipython](https://ipython.org/) for a lot of freedom and flexibility.