# Problems installing Scipy stack for Python3.6 on Pi-2

Tags: python, pi-2, packages

I am faced with an apparent time consuming problem or something else when I try to install scipy with pip for python3.6 on my RPi2 model B. OS is Raspbian minimal (jessie).

I am using a RPi2, and I successfully managed to follow the [suggested procedure](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/59391/72454) to install python3.6. But as pointed out by a commenter, I ran into problems with ssl when I tried to [install packages with pip](https://scipy.org/install.html).

I learned from [another thread on different subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43923085/cant-pip-install-packages-in-python-3-6-due-to-ssl-error) that I need to install ssl before I compile.

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.0/Python-3.6.0.tgz
tar xzvf Python-3.6.0.tgz
cd Python-3.6.0/
./configure
make
sudo make install
python3.6 -V
python3.6 -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3.6 -m pip install --user numpy 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I first ran into an error while installing scipy, but got past that with the [sugested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575587/cant-install-scipy-through-pip) `libatlas-base-dev gfortan` requirement.

<del>sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev gfortran</del>

<del>python3.6 -m pip install --user scipy</del>

the installation of scipy with pip takes a very long time (hours) and I am looking 
for a solution. I'll get back to this. the rest of the installation is now put on hold.

<del>python3.6 -m pip install --user matplotlib</del>

<del>python3.6 -m pip install --user ipython</del>

<del>python3.6 -m pip install --user jupyter</del>

<del>python3.6 -m pip install --user pandas</del>

<del>python3.6 -m pip install --user sympy</del>

<del>python3.6 -m pip install --user nose</del>

The upside of having to compile python3.6 a second time was a much faster compile the second time. On the other hand it takes a long time to install numpy, and that is why i split up the package installation. But it takes such a long time to install scipy that I am thinking there is another problem.

After hours of waiting for scipy to install, the green light on my PI has a constant green light (no blinking). I tried to open up another tty, but I can't log in there. So i got back to the tty with the installation script and hit `ctrl+c` to exit. I rebooted and I'm giving it another try.

But after waiting for another 7 hours I have the same situation. The constant green light on my PI, and no respons on tty2. I `ctrl+c` to exit.

Comment: I will look into [this solution](https://github.com/kleinee/jns) to make a Jupyter Notebook Server on Raspberry Pi 2.

Comment: Have you considered installing the compiled package from the Raspbian repo? `sudo apt-get install python3-scipy`

Comment: well the python3 preinstalled with jessie is python3.4, what will i get when I `sudo apt-get install python3-scipy`? After installing python3.6 I have python2.7, python3.4, and python3.6 on my pi-2

Comment: for good measure I did `sudo apt-get install python3-scipy`. But scipy does not show up in `python3.6 modules | less` or `python3 modules | less` although `dpkg -l python3-scipy`show it is installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the install also failing once with a constantly lit green LED. Then I noticed a quite warm cooling bridge in my Pi-top and I've cooled it with my fingers and suddenly the compile process went faster. I can't tell the total time but the green LED is now regularly blinking. I noticed that the RPi slows down quickly when the CPU is over 50...60 deg C. I will buy an USB fan to produce an airstream or maybe place the case vertically to increase convection cooling.