# Installing scipy 1.0.0 in python3 environment get decode byte error in _vq.pyx

Tags: software-installation

I am following the instructions in [How to install latest Scipy version on Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8308/how-to-install-latest-scipy-version-on-raspberry-pi)
and when I get to point of running:

```
python3 setup.py build
```

I get the following:

[image: result of build]

I tried looking at _vq.pyx but I didn't see any problems.
I also have tried clearing out the directory and trying again, but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 2):

Ben Nuttall's piwheels repository (https://www.piwheels.org/) has pre-compiled wheels for the Raspberry Pi. Currently it contains virtually all packages that can be downloaded from PyPi for Python 3.4 and 3.5 and is still expanding.

Current distributions of Raspbian Stretch are already configured to use the piwheels repo and the latest release of scipy can be installed with

```
sudo pip3 install scipy
```

On other distros (such as Raspbian Jessie) it can easily be added by creating the file '/etc/pip.conf' containing:

```
[global]
extra-index-url=https://www.piwheels.org/simple
```

Comment: `pip3 scipy` (I think that is right - this is from memory) should install the pi-specific wheel. I recently (October 2017) installed pre-configured libraries with `apt install python3-scipy python3-matplotlib`

Comment: Indeed. I just did a little test and installation of scipy and numpy took less than a minute on a Pi3B

Comment: For what it's worth the instructions in the top answer linked were posted in January 2018 (this year). The difference seems to be that the linked answer says `pip install scipy` won't work and builds from source instead; looks like they must have been mistaken if it does indeed work. Maybe you should post  a new answer if using pip does work to help others in future with the easiest way.

Comment: @Aurora0001 Sorry, I had not noticed the newer data. The answer as such is still valid, so I just expanded the answer to give more information