# Install opencv on Raspberry Pi 3 in a different way than compiling from source

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-stretch, opencv

I am using Raspbian Stretch on my RPi 3, I wanted to install OpenCV on it.
I did this before by following the instructions detailed [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/09/04/raspbian-stretch-install-opencv-3-python-on-your-raspberry-pi/) .
The problem is that this takes a very long time.
Lately, I've been looking in the internet, so I found in this [link](https://medium.com/@debugvn/installing-opencv-3-3-0-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-7db376f93961) that installing Opencv only needs to run these commands `pip install opencv-python` and `pip install opencv-contrib-python`. I tried it on Ubuntu with my PC and it worked well.
So my question is: **is it possible to install Opencv on a RPi 3 by just running these commands instead of compiling it from source?**

Comment: I really do not know , my fault, how to respond, but who or what is stopping you to try it ? Secondly - if the "manual: states it will take OpenCV time to install due to dependencies - why cannot just accept that?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is a bit late now.. I am already in the last step of the 'usual' method which is compiling from source. So at least I have to wait till it finishes to try this one.

Comment: Have you favorite snack / beverage  in the meantime. Cheers

Comment: As I read in this link: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/77307/found-a-pypi-package-for-opencv-contrib-but-cant-install-using-pip, precompiled binaries work only for some specific architectures (X86 and X86_64 but not ARM), which means that the only available solution to install Opencv on RPi is to compile it from source.

Comment: @singrium: precompiled wheels of opencv-python and opencv-contrib-python for arm / python 3 are available from piwheels (www.piwheels.org)

Comment: Sometime RTFM  REALLY answers questions. LOL ! Actually I was wondering if cross-compiling OpenCV would work "better" instead of running it on RPi,

Comment: @Dirk: Thank you, piwheels saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Precompiled wheels of opencv-python and opencv-contrib-python for arm / python 3 are available from piwheels (www.piwheels.org). On current Raspbian Stretch this already pre-configured.
On other distros (such as Raspbian Jessie) it can easily be added by creating the file '/etc/pip.conf' containing:

```
[global]
extra-index-url=https://www.piwheels.org/simple
```

See also [Installing scipy 1.0.0 in python3 environment](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88460/42636)

Comment: Di you try installing Opencv using piwheels before? As I said before, I am in the last step of compiling Opencv from source and I am afraid that if I abort it now and try piwheels it will not work.

Comment: Not 'in anger', meaning I downloaded it, but I cannot test if it's actually working ATM. Maybe you can create a virtual environment and try to download it in that environment.

Comment: This doesn’t work either; same “no matching distribution error”

Comment: @NoahPentecost on what model Pi / OS + version / Python version? And what is the exact command you use?

Comment: This worked on a RasPi 3 Model B v1.2, under Stretch. This is a fresh install, and I do not understand the claim that Stretch checks PiWheels out of the box. If really pre-configured, the system images we get are broken. Anyway, thanks @Dirk for compiling a solution (note that this solution checks PiWheel _after_, not before PyPi, as expected in some Stretch documentations).

Comment: Another comment: PiWheels provide OpenCV 3.4.4 at time of writing. For OpenCV 4.x, only install from source is available now. Sample [install tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/26/install-opencv-4-on-your-raspberry-pi/).