# Can not install Svgtools. Probably because off SciPy and numpy

Tags: pi-3, jessie-lite, pip

I was tring to install [PocketVj](https://github.com/magdesign/PocketVJ-CP-v3/) using [this](https://gist.github.com/baydam/a905e4878f54150f7da421e2c1d17a21/) guide from the Github page.
I installed all the dependencies using `sudo apt-get install...` with no problems. Followed by `sudo pip install --upgrade pip` again no problems.

```
Sudo pip install pjlink    and    sudo pip install python-osc
```

also worked without a problem. The problem I'm facing right now is svgtools. Here are the logs of my first attempt:

[image: I had to use a picture in order to stay in the 30000 character limit, sorry]
My little understanding told me that I had to install the latest version of Cython. I did that with `Sudo pip install Cython` and no problems. 
However now I'm getting different problems when trying to install Svgtools.

[image]

From that output I get that SciPy is missing and the wrong version of numpy installed.

So I tried to install SciPy with `sudo pip install SciPy` and only get:

```
    pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pip install SciPy
Collecting SciPy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/07/76/7e844757b9f3bf5ab9f951ccd3e4a8eed91ab8720b0aac8c2adcc2fdae9f/scipy-1.1.0.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: SciPy
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for SciPy ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-ev3H7e/SciPy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-YAq9vb --python-tag cp27:
  /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'python_requires'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  lapack_opt_info:
  openblas_info:
    libraries  not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  lapack_mkl_info:
  mkl_info:
    libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf']
    NOT AVAILABLE

    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
  numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_info:
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
  numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info
    NOT AVAILABLE

  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1427: UserWarning:
      Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
      the ATLAS environment variable.
    warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
  lapack_info:
    libraries lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1438: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
      the LAPACK environment variable.
    warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
  lapack_src_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1441: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
      the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
    warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
    NOT AVAILABLE

  Running from scipy source directory.
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-install-ev3H7e/SciPy/setup.py", line 474, in <module>
      setup_package()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-ev3H7e/SciPy/setup.py", line 470, in setup_package
      setup(**metadata)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 135, in setup
      config = configuration()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-ev3H7e/SciPy/setup.py", line 388, in configuration
      config.add_subpackage('scipy')
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 966, in add_subpackage
      caller_level = 2)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 935, in get_subpackage
      caller_level = caller_level + 1)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 872, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
      config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
    File "scipy/setup.py", line 15, in configuration
      config.add_subpackage('linalg')
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 966, in add_subpackage
      caller_level = 2)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 935, in get_subpackage
      caller_level = caller_level + 1)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 872, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
      config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
    File "scipy/linalg/setup.py", line 19, in configuration
      raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
  numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for SciPy
  Running setup.py clean for SciPy
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-ev3H7e/SciPy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" clean --all:

  `setup.py clean` is not supported, use one of the following instead:

    - `git clean -xdf` (cleans all files)
    - `git clean -Xdf` (cleans all versioned files, doesn't touch
                        files that aren't checked into the git repo)

  Add `--force` to your command to use it anyway if you must (unsupported).


  ----------------------------------------
  Failed cleaning build dir for SciPy
Failed to build SciPy
Installing collected packages: SciPy
  Running setup.py install for SciPy ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-ev3H7e/SciPy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-x1rbgQ/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

    Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
    with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

      - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                               release)
      - `pip install scipy`   (last SciPy release on PyPI)


    /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'python_requires'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    lapack_opt_info:
    openblas_info:
      libraries  not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_mkl_info:
    mkl_info:
      libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf']
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
    numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
    numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info
      NOT AVAILABLE

    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1427: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1438: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1441: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
      NOT AVAILABLE

    Running from scipy source directory.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ev3H7e/SciPy/setup.py", line 474, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ev3H7e/SciPy/setup.py", line 470, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 135, in setup
        config = configuration()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ev3H7e/SciPy/setup.py", line 388, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('scipy')
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 966, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 935, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 872, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy/setup.py", line 15, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('linalg')
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 966, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 935, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 872, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy/linalg/setup.py", line 19, in configuration
        raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
    numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-ev3H7e/SciPy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-x1rbgQ/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-ev3H7e/SciPy/
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem and sucesfull install SciPy in order to get Svgtools up and running?

Comment: It's scipy, not scipi

Comment: I fear you may be on your own with this.  Debian/Raspbian ensure that the packages in their repositories are all mutually consistent.  Once you download packages from other sources all bets are off.  I can't see that anyone will be able to help unless they have done exactly the same as you.

Comment: Please paste text rather than screen shots. It should work if you use the '{}' tool to keep the formatting. I cannot read the images.

Comment: I originaly tried to do that but reached the limit of 30000 characters.

Comment: If you are actually running Jessie (which is obsolete) I suggest you install Stretch. This should have pre-compiled wheels for all common Python packages. See https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/piwheels/

Comment: Yeah you are right. But unfortunately PocketVJ advice you to use Jessie in order for it to work perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where possible, installing packages through `apt` will save you a lot of trouble. Numpy and SciPy (note the -Py, not -Pi, as it's *Python*—not specifically Pi related) both have a lot of dependencies, and Pip generally tries to build the code directly rather than using pre-built packages as apt will.

The dependencies of svgtools are listed in the [requirements.txt](https://github.com/vsoch/svgtools/blob/master/requirements.txt) file of their repository. They are:

```
networkx
numpy
scipy
scikit-learn
pandas
scikit-image
```

So, you can try installing all of the above from the package manager:

```
sudo apt-get install python-networkx python-numpy python-scipy python-sklearn python-pandas
```

(`scikit-image` is not in the repositories so will have to be installed through Pip)

**It may be wise to try to `pip uninstall ...` for any packages you have previously installed first**.

Then, you can try running:

```
pip install svgtools
```

to see if compatibility is better with the system packages than installing numpy etc through Pip. That should automatically install `scikit-image` as required but hopefully will not need to build scikit-learn at all, avoiding the issues you've been having.

Comment: Your answer helped me alot. Trying to install the modules using apt-get and self compiling SciPy resulted in me being able to install svgtools. I used [these](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/77856/89828) instructions to compile SciPy. It seems like the pre compiled versions are sometimes not fully compatible with Raspbian (Jessy).