# Not able to install the latest version of Scipy(1.2.0) on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, python-3

I have Scipy version 0.18.2 on my RaspberryPi 3. However, I need the find_peaks() function which is only available on higher versions.

I followed this [link](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8308/how-to-install-latest-scipy-version-on-raspberry-pi) to install scipy.

But the `python3 setup.py build` pauses here:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy-1.15.4-py3.5-linux-
armv7l.egg/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: 
warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " 
"#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
#warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
^~~~~~~
```

I'm working on latest version of numpy(1.15.4).

Any other inputs on how to implement scipy's find_peaks() would also be helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're using Raspbian Stretch (using RPF image) you should get 1.2 with pip3: `sudo pip3 install scipy`. This will install using a binary wheel from piwheels. Don't use sudo if you're in a virtual environment

Comment: Thanks for your response. Pip doesn't seem to work.. I am using pip behind a proxy I've tried the answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149422/using-pip-behind-a-proxy) with 228 upvotes . It gives me this error for any pip command.                                              >>>TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'

Comment: AFAIK you just need a newer version of requests/pip. I would uninstall `python3-pip` and then use https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py . Make sure to use `sudo python3 get-pip.py` to install pip.

Comment: when  do sudo python3 get-pip.py .. It says "retrying" a lot of times and ends with this error -->  "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: )  No matching distribution found for pip"

Comment: I have noticed that you have linked [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/94993/19949) but since it got a answer posted after your question I wonder if you have checked that too? If it works, we could close this question as a duplicate. Thanks.