# Error in pyarrow while installing Apache Beam in Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-3

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ and should be installing the Apache Beam SDK to connect it to Google Cloud Platform services such as Pub/Sub, Dataflow, and BigQuery. I've got Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) installed as my OS. I've been following the instructions very carefully on a community tutorial in GCP:

https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/ardu-pi-serial-part-2

Ran the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/community.git
cd community/tutorials/ardu-pi-serial-part-2
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install -r beam-requirements.txt
pip install apache-beam[gcp]
```

Then I get the error while installing apache-beam:

```
creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7
-- Running cmake for pyarrow
cmake -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/home/pi/community/tutorials/ardu-pi-serial-part-2/venv/bin/python2  - 
DPYARROW_BOOST_USE_SHARED=on -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release /tmp/pip-install-L4MeVK/pyarrow
unable to execute 'cmake': No such file or directory
error: command 'cmake' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow
Building wheel for googledatastore (setup.py) ... done
Created wheel for googledatastore: filename=googledatastore-7.0.2-py2-none-any.whl size=18154 
sha256=d819df28a4cf473e25913fd34bb56506651a3c81b26d66fc2b6b3afede341f8d
Stored in directory: 
/home/pi/.cache/pip/wheels/a6/07/b7/048bd604cfadf321bc995c1d2b6e92770bf852e2209b9dcc97
Building wheel for proto-google-cloud-datastore-v1 (setup.py) ... done
Created wheel for proto-google-cloud-datastore-v1: filename=proto_google_cloud_datastore_v1-0.90.4- 
py2-none-any.whl size=23752 sha256=70834e2d3c64fdfbf04a6326b27b0ec85d01ffd408f15df7b0cefa055265c9b5
Stored in directory: 
/home/pi/.cache/pip/wheels/80/86/e7/3e30f012839d7608dc34c5bb5087356307a028c7e1c44c3075
Building wheel for grpc-google-iam-v1 (setup.py) ... done
Created wheel for grpc-google-iam-v1: filename=grpc_google_iam_v1-0.12.3-py2-none-any.whl size=18500 
sha256=0c5278ed422f0a616fdc3b54de4a750348441ce9f945cb0a1eaa2d5e9b7d94f3
Stored in directory: 
/home/pi/.cache/pip/wheels/77/4d/90/443c1cecdcfbf9d97f6e567304aacddc234cf1b26e48c6f0e5
Building wheel for googleapis-common-protos (setup.py) ... done
Created wheel for googleapis-common-protos: filename=googleapis_common_protos-1.51.0-py2-none-any.whl 
size=77593 sha256=910992bfc3cf5b58189e21114ccc2c7bca83a91bedd02cdb06d8a2e783b97007
Stored in directory: 
/home/pi/.cache/pip/wheels/56/af/44/f0c28e985bc224ffb90612f7cdeef432ba4fbd5d15485ab271
Successfully built apache-beam crcmod dill fastavro future hdfs httplib2 pymongo oauth2client avro 
pyvcf googledatastore proto-google-cloud-datastore-v1 grpc-google-iam-v1 googleapis-common-protos
Failed to build pyarrow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

What could be the reason this is happening and how would I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent answer for this at streamlit.
It worked for me. Another forum member claimed it worked for them.

It is a substantial build:
disk space to build: ~ 5.6 GB for llvm, ~0.6 GB for arrow
disk space of the install: ~ 0.7 GB

Because I had installed some of the Python packages previously (Cython, most specifically) as the pi user, but not with sudo, I had to re-install those packages using sudo  for the last step of pyarrow installation to work:

> sudo python setup.py install

Note that you don't need to install streamlit if all you want is pyarrow.
But that was the motivation for pyarrow in that environment.

**I've copied the majority of the post from @shadanan here (verbatim)**:

Here are the steps I used:

Prepare your LD_LIBRARY_PATH. You’ll want to put this in .bashrc or .zshrc.

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

Install llvm-10 from source 1 – unfortunately, arrow requires llvm-10 at a minimum and the latest llvm in the raspbian package repos was llvm-9. If you can get llvm-10 in some other way, do it that way instead of this. It took a whole night to build llvm-10 on my poor Raspberry Pi.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git
$ cd llvm-project
$ git fetch --tags
$ git checkout llvmorg-10.0.1
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" \
    -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;libcxx;libcxxabi" \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=On \
    ../llvm
$ make -j4
$ sudo make install
```

Install Apache Arrow from source. I adapted instructions from here: https://gist.github.com/heavyinfo/04e1326bb9bed9cecb19c2d603c8d521 1

```
$ wget https://github.com/apache/arrow/archive/apache-arrow-1.0.1.tar.gz
$ tar xzf apache-arrow-1.0.1.tar.gz
$ cd arrow-apache-arrow-1.0.1/cpp
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ export ARROW_HOME=/usr/local
$ cmake \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$ARROW_HOME \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=lib \
    -DARROW_WITH_BZ2=ON \
    -DARROW_WITH_ZLIB=ON \
    -DARROW_WITH_ZSTD=ON \
    -DARROW_WITH_LZ4=ON \
    -DARROW_WITH_SNAPPY=ON \
    -DARROW_PARQUET=ON \
    -DARROW_PYTHON=ON \
    -DARROW_BUILD_TESTS=OFF \
    ..
$ make -j4
$ sudo make install
$ cd ../../python
$ python3 setup.py build_ext --build-type=release --with-parquet
$ sudo python3 setup.py install
```

Install streamlit.

```
$ sudo pip3 install streamlit
```

Run streamlit as follows. You can also put the LD_PRELOAD in your .bashrc or .zshrc. I think there’s a way to avoid having this 2, but it looked like I’d have to rebuild either llvm-10 or arrow, and I didn’t want to spend any more time on this.

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libatomic.so.1.2.0 streamlit run <python_script.py>
```

If someone else goes through this and can simplify these steps, I’m sure the community would appreciate it.

Comment: Minor note: if you install a lot of libraries from source, you may consider adding `/usr/local/lib` to `/etc/ld.so.conf`, instead of relying on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

if it really is cmake that it can't find:

```
sudo apt-get install cmake
```

But at that point it will probably complain that  it can't find arrow (the C++ libraries).

in which case, see:
https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/docs/source/developers/cpp/building.rst

with the key parts (given Raspberry Pi):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake
git clone https://github.com/apache/arrow.git
cd arrow/cpp
mkdir release
cd release
cmake ..
make
make install
```

you may run out of swap in which case see:
[How to install latest Scipy version on Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8308/how-to-install-latest-scipy-version-on-raspberry-pi#77856)
but once arrow C++ is built and installed
you can try

```
pip install pyarrow
```

I can't get pyarrow to install, it's looking for

> -- Found the Arrow core static library: /usr/local/lib/libarrow.a
> -- Could NOT find ArrowPython (missing: ArrowPython_DIR)
> -- Checking for module 'arrow-python'
> --   No package 'arrow-python' found
> CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137
> (message):
> Could NOT find ArrowPython (missing: ARROW_PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR
> ARROW_PYTHON_LIB_DIR) (found version "1.0.1")

, but hope this gets you closer...