# How to install pyarrow (for parquet file format) on raspberry pi (RPi 4)?

Tags: python, pi-4

I use Raspberry Pi 4 (4 GB RAM) and Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster). I'm would like to run some python programs to capture some data 24/7. Raspberry pi would act as the data collector and another machine would analyze/process the data.
My preferred way to store the data and later process on another machine would be: parquet file format

To install pyarrow on the raspberry pi for python3:

```
pip3 install pyarrow
```

I get the message:

```
Failed building wheel for pyarrow
  Running setup.py clean for pyarrow
   Failed to build pyarrow
    Installing collected packages: pyarrow
      Running setup.py install for pyarrow ... error
   ....

Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-0d4i0qjw/pyarrow/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-dn2pfxo3/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-0d4i0qjw/pyarrow/
```

Afterwards I tried to follow the advice
[https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/110958/error-in-pyarrow-while-installing-apache-beam-in-raspberry-pi][1]

When running "make" I get the following error:

```
In file included from /home/pi/pyarrow/arrow/cpp/src/arrow/util/basic_decimal.cc:31:
/home/pi/pyarrow/arrow/cpp/src/arrow/util/int128_internal.h:26:10: fatal error: boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Does someone could advice or help how to install pyarrow on the raspberry pi to be able to be used with python?

Thank you

Comment: Going by https://www.piwheels.org/project/pyarrow/ its never made it on a Pi !  Looking at https://pypi.org/project/pyarrow/ and https://arrow.apache.org/install/ both use pip not pip3 The latter has a long list of steps under Debian for the C package - not sure if running those first would bring the header file in for you.

Comment: @Andyroo thank you for your answer. At least it confirms, that I was not doing something wrong. Do you know, if there are plans that pyarrow will be available for raspberry pi in the future? For now I guess I need to use one of the alternative formats available for a dataframe (like csv or hdf)..

Answer (score 2):

OS: Ubuntu 20.04

I was able to install pyarrow using this command, on a Rpi4 (8gb ram, not sure if tech specs help):

```
PYARROW_BUNDLE_ARROW_CPP=1 PYARROW_CMAKE_OPTIONS="-DARROW_ARMV8_ARCH=armv8-a" pip install pyarrow
```

Found this on a [Jira ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-9744).

Have only verified the installation with `python3 -c "import pyarrow"` and yet to use the package in some code. Will report back if I see any problems further on.

Comment: Confirmed on Ubuntu 20.04 on Pi4 - thank you!   (Note: I wasn't able to get this work on Buster on a different Pi4)

Comment: @James_SO forgot to add that. I have tried it on an Ubuntu image only.